# How to use Subdomain for a custom CMS of the main domain website?

Tags: seo, domains, web-crawlers, cms, search

Should I use a subdomain for a custom CMS of the main domain website? Like `cms.domain.com`. As it will be a CMS, I will disallow a search crawler for indexing. Will this hurt SEO for the Main Domain?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, anything you put on the internet that you tell search engines to not crawl will not affect anything else on the internet.

In this case, any content on the domain, either as a subdomain or even a subdirectory, that is blocked via robots.txt will not impact the SEO for the site at the root of the main domain.

I suppose it's possible that anything Really Bad™ that happened on those uncrawled subsites might reflect badly on the main site and negatively affect the SEO. But we're talking malicious software and other things that search engines want to protect their users from. I'm not sure anyone would have tested this, but it's possible. Especially if there are any links from the main site to the sub site.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about your third paragraph.